# What does $[M:N]$ mean, where $M,N$ are modules and $N$ is a submodule of $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

What does $[M:N]$ mean? where $M,N$ are modules and $N$ is a submodule of $M$.
The context is the following equation:
$$\text{disc}(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)=[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]^2\text{disc}(\mathcal{O}_K)$$ where $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is the ring of algebraic integers and $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$(here $\alpha$ is a algebraic integer).

Comment: Any more context? Could it be the cardinality of the quotient module?

Comment: I am fairly sure that it means the index of a subgroup = cardinality of the quotien group.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks, and do you know where is this equation from? Or the name of this equation?

Comment: @Danny It is a property of the discriminant of a power basis expressed in terms of the discriminant of the ring of integers. I didn't find a reference but I remember encountered it somewhere.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts Thank you!

Comment: Your equation is a general property. See e.g. Marcus' book "Number Fields", chapter 2, formula c) in exercise 27.